Is the magnetic field generated by a permanent magnet always conservative?
Ignoring for a moment dissipative long time effects.
Since there is no energy exchange with external sources (contrary to the case of fields generated by currents, that need a generator), the field must be conservative. Am I right?
Bonus question: given that there is no magnetic monopole, and that work done by the Lorentz force on a charge is always zero, how do you check that the work on a closed loop is zero? Should you use a magnetic dipole? (but then it depends on the orientation...)

But the lorentz for is nonzero on a charge moving relative to the magnetic field source as long as the direction of motion is not (anti)parallel to the field lines.

@Triatticus being the vector product of field and velocity it is always perpendicular to velocity, isn't it?

Well the resulting force is yes, but that product need not necessarily be zero save for the situation mentioned. You asserted it was always zero but that's not true at all. Otherwise a magnetic field couldn't cause a charge particle to move in circular motion.

sorry! I meant the work generated, I will amend the question , thanks

For a permanent magnet it is possible that $\mathbf{H}$ follows the condition
$$\nabla \times \mathbf{H}=0, $$
since there may be no free currents $\mathbf{J}_f=0$. See the scalar magnetic potential. But this does not mean that the $\mathbf{B}$ field is conservative. A permanent magnet is characterized by an intrinsic or permanent magnetization $\mathbf{M}$, therefore
$$\frac{\mathbf{B}}{\mu_0}-\mathbf{M}=\mathbf{H}\to \mathbf{B}=\mu_0 \mathbf{M} \to \nabla \times \mathbf{B}= \mu_0 \nabla \times \mathbf{M}=\mu_0 \mathbf{J}_\mathrm{bound}. $$
Which is not conservative.
